# A function return sth unexpected in C

Tags: c

Objective ：Compare the two integers entered and type the smaller one. If the two integers equal, then program gives a warning and starts the new loop.

Platform : Visual Studio 2012.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int get_lesser(int a , int b);
int main(void)
{
    int a , b;
    printf("1: Enter two integers: ");
    while(scanf("%d%d" , &a , &b) == 2)
    {
        printf("THe smaller of the two integers entered is %d.\n" , get_lesser(a , b));
        printf("2: Enter two numbers: ");
    } 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int get_lesser(int a , int b)
{
    if(a == b)
        printf("The two integers equal.\n");
    else if(a > b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}
```

I created a function-get_lesser.

The thing I don't understand is : Every time I enter two same integers， I will be told the smaller of the two is 24.
Where does 24 come from??
Thank you.

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings. The compiler can see that not all paths return a value in a function that returns int.

Comment: It's because you're on a little-endian system. On a big-endian system, you would see the correct answer, namely 42.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, somehow I feel that 24 and 42 fit into the same byte anyway, but I agree if your function doesn't return a value magic can happen. And maybe the question to the mother of all awnsers is: What is the lesser int?

Answer (score 6):

Because you do not return anything here:

```
if(a == b)
        printf("The two integers equal.\n");
```

If `a > b` this will return `b`:

```
else if(a > b)
        return b;
```

If `a < b` this will return `a`:

```
else
    return a;
```

But this statement does not return anything from the `get_lesser` function

```
if(a == b)
    printf("The two integers equal.\n");
```

A better way of comparing would be:

```
int get_lesser(int a , int b)
{
    if(a == b)
        return 0; //Equal args
    else if(a > b)
        return 1; //first arg is greater
    else
        return -1; //second arg is greater
}
```

Now use the return values to check what was returned - note - your order of arguments is important here.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't return anything when `a` equals to `b`. Change it to return an `int`:

```
if (a == b)
{
    printf("The two integers equal.\n");
    return a;
}
```

Note here it's important to use a block because there are more than one statement.

Answer (score 0):

as al-Acme said yo do not return anything at the first if statement but printf function return the number of characters it prints to the screen,  i think 24 comes from printf.

Comment: If a function doens't return a value while it should return a value, the returned value is undefined, so it can be any value.

Comment: You are right! I just tried to give a hint about the unanswered part of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as @al-Acme described, if they are equal, nothing is returned abd that is what is causing your bug.

Anyway, here is a fixed version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int get_lesser(int a , int b);
int main(void)
{
    int a , b;
    printf("1: Enter two integers: ");
    while(scanf("%d%d" , &a , &b) == 2)
    {
        if(get_lesser(a , b)!=(a+b+1))
         {
          printf("\nThe smaller of the two integers entered is %d.\n" , get_lesser(a , b));
          break;
         }
        else
         {
           printf("\nThe two integers equal.\n");
           printf("2: Enter two numbers: ");
         }
    } 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int get_lesser(int a , int b)
{
    if(a == b)
        return a+b+1;
    else if(a > b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}
```

What I have done in this code is that if `a` and `b` are equal, the function `get_lesser()` returns `a+b+1`. It returns this to avoid a few cases ( this is in case `a` or `b` is `0` ), and thus, this code works for all inputs ( well, all the inputs that I have tried anyway )